# Is it possible to get in docker container without root permission of host, when docker needs sudo to run?

Tags: server, permissions, security, docker

To my knowledge, people usually open docker group for regular users, so they could have a separate environment to do almost anything without root permission of host.

But if docker command needs to be run by `sudo`, like `sudo docker exec -it CONTAINER /bin/bash` , is it a good way to hide information, for instance, source code in container?

My question is, to be more specific, **if `sudo` is necessary to run `docker`, is it possible to see what's inside container, or even access it, without root permission?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to run Docker as root.

Docker has a ["rootless" mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/), that allows Docker containers to be run in userspace. However, there are some limitations to this operating mode listed in the linked documentation. In this mode, the user in question has full access to containers and their contents.

*I don't personally have any experience with running Docker in rootless mode though.*

If you want to run Docker as a system-wide service, it requires `root` access, or membership of the `docker` group. In this mode, you can run the following command (as member of `docker` group - using nginx as an example, and provided `bash` is in the container):

```
docker exec -it nginx /bin/bash
```

You get into the terminal of the container (as root):

```
root@e209bdb1fe51:/#
```

So even if you're not root on local machine (but a member of the `docker` group), you will be root inside the container.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry for my words isn't clear. I mean, for user not in docker group and they don't have root permission, could they still get in container? To be more specific, if docker command can only run by `sudo docker ...`, are people still possible to access container without root?

Comment: Please edit your original question to clearly state the question that you want answered.